# corda, How could Bob uses Alice's public key to encrypt msg, and then Alice uses her private key to decrypt msg?

Tags: corda

Does Corda's private key and public keys use for signature and verification, not for encryption and decryption?

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your question, it's about public-key cryptography. So the idea generally is that a key pair is created for bob (public and private keys. Alice can then use bob's public key, to encrypt a message that only bob can decrypt. That's why bob's decryption key is called the private key, which is to say that it should never be shared.

Corda is ultimately just carefully managing the pairs of keys for the entities that wish to communicate. It's still just going to be pairs of keys though at the end of the day. That's the way the messages work.

You can find a video I put together specifically on this subject that includes the math on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzYOlHPMlMs